# Java: instantiate parametrized class by passing types as method parameter

Tags: java, generics, parameters, guava

My problem is that there is a generic class called `TypedProducer<K, V>` for key and value and I do have to instantiate it from configuration (let's say config tells me **during runtime** that key is `Integer` and value is `String` in configuration during runtime but it can be any `Object` subtype really) so I don't know the types beforehand.

How can I instantiate `TypedProducer` by passing parameters? Or even create `SourceTypedClassProvider<keyType, valueType>` in the first place from `.class` objects?

```
public class SourceTypedClassProvider {

  public static TypedProducer<?, ?> instantiateTypedProducer(
      Class<?> keyType, Class<?> valueType) {
    //should return instance of TypedProducer<Integer, String>
  }
}
```

I know there's something like `TypeToken` in guava, but would it help me at all in this scenario when types have to be first gotten from configuration?

EDIT:
To be honest `TypedProducer` implementation shouldn't make a difference (you can treat it as if I were instantiating e.g. a `Map<K, V>`) but if it makes it easier part of the implementation below:

```
public class TypedProducer<K, V> {
  ExternalApiProducer<K, V> externalApiProducer;

  public TypedProducer() {
    externalApiProducer = new ExternalApiProducer<>();
  }

  public Map<K, V> produceRecords() {
    //some code that calls externalApiProducer to produce records 
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the constructor (or factory method) of `TypedProducer`.

Comment: You can't do this in Java. Generics are static time only, so you can't get a dynamically parameterized result

Comment: Is it actually something like the following that you want? `public <K,V> TypedProducer<K, V> instantiateTypedProducer(Class<K> keyType, Class<V> valueType) { return new TypedProducer<>(); }`

Comment: If you only know types at runtime, then use a raw type, because due to runtime type erasure that's all you've got anyway.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos It is, but if I make it like that I only defer the problem: parameters `Class<K> keyType` and `Class<V> valueType` are unused and I will still have to somehow *convert* `String.class` and `Integer.class` into a variable type so I can get: `TypedProducer<Integer, String> = instantiateTypedProducer()`

Comment: @Bohemian That's what I think I will have to do if I won't find another way. But problem of this approach is that in rest of the code I will have to deal with duck-typing in order to find out what's the true type of key and value

Answer (score 0):

Given the code shown in your question, this works:

```java
public static TypedProducer<?, ?> instantiateTypedProducer(Class<?> keyType, Class<?> valueType) {
    return new TypedProducer<>();
}
```

I would guess that having a `TypedProducer<?, ?>` (with unspecified bounds) is useless though. Don't you want to end up with something like `TypedProducer<Integer, String>`?

---

Given the code you've shown for `TypedProducer` and `ExternalApiProducer`, clients can simply do this:

```java
TypedProducer<Integer, String> producer = new TypedProducer<>();
```

There's no need for a `instantiateTypedProducer()` method, or to have references to the `Integer` or `String` classes.

You'll need to provide enough code to explain why you can't use the obvious and straightforward approach. Justify your need to complicate things.

Comment: That's exactly the case: How can I end up with `TypedProducer<Integer, String>` if I only have `String.class` and `Integer.class` after reading config?

Comment: @GoMati Your question is unclear. Please see my update and amend your question if it is not resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and clear explanation! The reason to complicate it is simple: I do not know the `K` and `V` types of `TypedProducer<K,V>` until runtime (when I read them from configuration and only then I can make `.class` out of them), so straightforward approach is (most probably) out of the question.

Comment: @GoMati The purpose of generic types is to be able to ensure the type safety of your code at compile-time. So it's difficult to understand how you want to use types read from a config file at runtime in conjunction with a generically typed class. Perhaps an example of the code you'd like to be able to write against this API would make it more clear.